# webpack DllPlugin: WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_dll_reference is not defined

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to build standard webpack dll example from their repo: [dll](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/dll) and [dll-user](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/dll-user).

I've added `sourceType: 'umd'` to configs of DllPlugin and DllReferencePlugin. Imports like `require('beta/b')` are processed normally, and webpack can successfully build both `dll` and `dll-user` projects.

But, then in resulting bundle of `dll-user` I see following:

```
/***/ "dll-reference dll_alpha":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** external "dll_alpha" ***!
  \****************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_dll_reference_dll_alpha__;

/***/ }),

/***/ "dll-reference dll_beta":
/*!***************************!*\
  !*** external "dll_beta" ***!
  \***************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_dll_reference_dll_beta__;

/***/ }),
```

These `WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_dll_reference` vars aren't defined anywhere. And thus, it doesn't work despite build is successful.

I don't understand, where should I get these vars from. Should smth else be configured, which isn't described in docs/examples?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?